# Этимология слова "будни"

Tags: этимология, словообразование

Как я понимаю, слово "будни" состоит из двух частей "бу-дни". Со второй частью все понятно, а что означает первая? А еще — может ли это слово употребляться в единственном числе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, Ваше членение ошибочно.

Будни  - множественное от "буден" ("будьнъ"), которое в свою очередь - краткое прилагательное от основы, родственной "будить" - приводить в состояние бодрствование.
Единственно могу добавить, "будьнъ день" вполне возможно как исходная форма, но о слиянии "рефрена" "бу***дьнъ день***" речи не идет, "день" просто отпал.
Да и вообще "рефрен" здесь был весьма условный.

//-----  (добавление)

Как автор "принятого" ответа прошу учесть, что по одному из вопросов имеется альтернативное мнение Людмилы (о возможной гаплологии). Я не согласен, но не хочу, чтобы мое утверждение воспринималось как истина в последней инстанции.

Answer (score 4):

Буденъ день - явление гаплологии, когда выпадает один из одинаково звучащих идущих друг за другом слогов.

Результатом гаплологии являются, например, слова «знаменосец» (из «знаменоносец»), «минералогия» (из «минералология»), «близорукий» (из «близозоркий»), «трагикомедия» (из «трагикокомедия»), «коричневатый» (из «коричневоватый»), «радушие» (из «радодушие»), «курносый» (из «корноносый», от «корнать» и «нос»).
http://vslovare.ru/slovo/gaplologija

Об этимологии "буден"уже сказали.

Единственное число возможно в просторечии - "будень"(будний день).В древнерусском периоде слово и было в ед. числе, позже появилась рабочая неделя + праздничный день, ещё позже "выходной"."Будень" в ед.ч.  вышло из употребления , осталось только во множ.ч.

Comment: Людмила, [буд'э***н***] и [д'э***нь***]
Гаплология?

Comment: Гаплология- "будень" из "будьнъ день".

Comment: Я об этом и спрашиваю. В первом случае Н - твердый, ао втором мягкий. В первом случае "ерь", во втором - "есть". В историческом звучании слова даже не похожи.

Comment: >"Будень" в ед.ч. вышло из употребления 

Кое-где ещё **употребляется** в разговорной форме. *Будень* или даже *будень день*.

Answer (score 3):

Не-а. Будни - это от будильника.

Comment: Ха! Да, вполне себе популярное объяснение. Только не "от", а "общий корень".

Answer (score 3):

Будни от "будень". По Фасмеру от ср. польск.  budny dzienґ "будний день", букв. "день бдения" от budьnъ : buditi, русск. будиґть. Ср. болг. буден "бодрый, бдительный", словен. buґdЌn "бодрый, веселый" (Грот, Фил. Раз. 891; Бернекер 1, 96; Брюкнер 47; Преобр. 1, 50).

Comment: И это верно.

Answer (score 0):

БУ́ДЕНЬ, дня, чол.

1. Не святковий, робочий, будній день. Шовкова плахта не к будню, а к святу (Номис, 1864, № 11 131); В будень і в неділю Головоньку йому змиє [мати] (Тарас Шевченко, I, 1951, 315); В будні обоє вони працювали (Панас Мирний, II, 1954, 80); Василь Васильович воліє приїжджати до Опанасовича не в дні свят.., а в будні (Олексій Полторацький, Дит. Гоголя, 1954, 157).
2. перен. Трудове, повсякденне життя. Вона бажала кращого, празникового життя. А у службі усе будень, усе загайно. Найнялась — продалась (Михайло Коцюбинський, I, 1955, 64); [Орфей:] Тепер же день робітний, тяжкий будень, не можу я, не смію святкувати! (Леся Українка, I, 1951, 451); Оповідати ввечері він любить Про сутички, про будні бойові (Максим Рильський, Мости, 1948, 91);
   //  перев. мн. Одноманітне безрадісне існування; буденщина. Вона.. знала, що повинна щось робити, а не скніти в своїх сірих буднях (Олесь Донченко, I, 1956, 387).

Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 1, 1970. — Стор. 247.